# Never received notification that an answer to my question was posted

Tags: bug, answers, notifications

I just happened to look at a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173789/146446) I asked a month ago and noticed that an [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174361/146446) was posted a week after I asked the question. I was surprised to see an answer since I didn't recall ever receiving any notification that an answer was posted.

Sure enough, when I looked in my inbox, I didn't see any message from Code Review indicating that an answer was posted.

The day after I posted my question, a user added a comment, and I did receive an inbox notification for that:

> [image: inbox]

In the responses section of my profile activity, both the answer and comment responses are there, however, there is only a message in my inbox regarding the comment.

> [image: responses]

I've received other answer notification from other Stack Exchange sites since this Code Review answer was posted, so this seems to just be an issue with the Code Review site or with this specific post.

> [image: other sites]

Comment: The post was [deleted ten minutes after it was posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/174361/revisions), which may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Interesting. I didn't notice that. That could be part of the problem. I wonder if post deletion and then undeletion always causes problems with the inbox notifications. This may not be Code Review specific then after all.

Comment: @TotZam That's probably it, yes. It would surprise me if there isn't already a question about it on the [big meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), but I'm not in a position to go look for it at the moment.

Comment: @Mast I originally didn't realize the answer had been deleted/undeleted and thought this was a Code Review specific bug, so that is why I posted this question here. Now that I know that happened, this is very likely the same problem as this Meta Stack Exchange post: [Temporarily deleted answer missing from asker's inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126658/297762), although that question never received any response.